# Mobile app screen visual design critique

Tags: interface-design, critique

[image]

This is a hi-fideltiy mockup of one of the mobile apps I am designing. I personally don't like the design that much.

However, I cannot pinpoint the issues in some objective way for me to improve it.

Here are a set of questions I have:

1. Are the slider arrows looking good?
2. Is the alignment of text correct? How should I align the fields and values in that blue box
3. Is the font good?
4. I want to follow iOS guidelines ... This design seems very "flat".
5. Does a rectangular button follow iOS guidelines?
6. Is the font size too small for the Buyer/Seller/Profile icon below?

Comment: As this is written now, it is too broad for us to really answer.  Per our [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682), you'll want to narrow the scope of your question a bit

Comment: You could take a look at how others solve the same issues, check for examples here http://www.mobile-patterns.com/ and here https://pttrns.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. The arrows are OK. They look acceptable to me(average, no new ideas)
2. The address would look better centered. The blue box has options of right aligning the labels and I would decrease the space between each line.
3. I suggest increasing the font size.
4. It is very "flat". I suggest decreasing the margins and rounding corners(slightly).
5. No answer.
6. Yes